# Spring boot multi tenancy per schema issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm creating the app with multi-tenant support. 
I did as done in this project on GitHub: https://github.com/singram/spring-boot-multitenant

It works fine while manually add schema and tables for it. It sets up schema name automatically. But how I can generate schemas programmatically, not manually?  
 
P.S: I want generate schema for user after his registration in the system.

Comment: Getting 404 error from your github link

Comment: Look for `SchemaUpdate` class in hibernate

Comment: 404 is corrected

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: Ok i will post my answer with example

Comment: Thanx in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update schema manually you should use `SchemaUpdate` class of hibernate along with this you will have to create a reference of `StandardServiceRegistry` interface which will have the information regarding database connectivity and `MetadataImplementor` reference.

Use `MetadataSources` to create reference of `MetadataImplementor`. We need to tell hibernate that to create tables for these classes for this `MetadataSources` provides method `addAnnotatedClass()`.

**Here is the example**:

```
try {
    Map < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();
    map.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
    map.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    map.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    map.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + databaseName);
    map.put(Environment.USER, "root");
    map.put(Environment.PASS, "root");
    map.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "false");
    StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(map)
        .build();
    try {
        MetadataSources metaDataSource = new MetadataSources(ssr);
        Set < Class << ? extends Object >> classes = getClassInPackage("com.domain");
        for (Class << ? extends Object > c : classes) {
            metaDataSource.addAnnotatedClass(c);
        }
        final MetadataImplementor metadata = (MetadataImplementor) metaDataSource
                                                                    .buildMetadata();
        metadata.validate();
        SchemaUpdate su = new SchemaUpdate(ssr, metadata);
        su.setHaltOnError(true);
        su.setDelimiter(";");
        su.setFormat(true);
        su.execute(true, true);
    } finally {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(ssr);
    }
} catch (GenericJDBCException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code uses MYSQL database configuration . To get entity classes in a package i have used `reflections` . you can add below dependency to your **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

And the code for `getClassInPackage()` method is as below:

```
private Set < Class << ? extends Object >> getClassInPackage(String packagePath) {
            Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packagePath,
                new SubTypesScanner(false));
            Set < Class << ? extends Object >> allClasses =
                reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
            return allClasses;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand how to make the first snippet of code working! Should it be in a class with @configuration annotation or declared as a component?

Comment: Also, how can we set the name of the new tenant?

Comment: The above written code is used in my service to create database for every user who does signup to my application. Also i use userName - (which is a signup field) to create tenant name